# DisplayMemberPath in Listbox

Tags: wpf, struct, listbox

I have struct which includes 2 strings : Name, Uid. I add this struct into listbox and I want that the listbox to show only a Name of struct. How I can do this??

Thanks!

```
   public struct ListItemEl
{
    public string Name;
    public string Uid;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those need to be public [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) if you want [`DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) (which should just to be set to `Name`) to work.

Comment: I am a beginner in programming. Can you explain me in detail how I can solve this problem?